# what does it mean when a transaction contain multiple inputs?

Tags: transactions, transaction-input

Just like https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/230636ab4f285ca5e9f4c32dbae581c10d491a99493d8733c594af780f1edc5e

what does it mean when a transaction contain multiple inputs?
as i know, an transaction should be signed by the sender`s the private key.
However there are a lot of sender in one transaction, how does it happen? 
thanks

Comment: It is just like in the real world, you combine multiple bills and coins to pay for an item. Two bills of 1 USD to form a payment of 2 USD.

Comment: ...and in the real world, your ownership is proven by possession of each the bills. In bitcoin, this is proven by each of the signatures.

Answer (score 2):

A single transaction may contain multiple inputs and outputs. It is not the transaction that is signed by the sender, but each input. The signature is in the `scriptSig` field of each input.

See http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/transaction